# how to generate font obfuscated key for IDPF

Tags: fonts, key, obfuscation, epub3

I have written the font obfuscated algorithm using IDPF method, but do we have to generate any obfuscated key after that as the fonts are not getting displayed on ibooks but they are encrypted well with my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

After the conversion for obfustication process, the encryption.xml was created in the "META-INF" folder.

You need to match the OPF font path and URI path in the encryption.xml

For Example:

```
<enc:CipherReference URI="OPS/fonts/font name.otf"/>
```